# Zend EmailAddress Validation returning multiple errors

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-validate

I am unable to make Zend_Validate_EmailAddress show only 1 error message when the user enter invalid email address. The code is

```
$email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
$email->setLabel('Email: ')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addValidator('EmailAddress',true, array(... error msgs ...))
    ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(array( ... db + table + col details ... ),true, array(... error msgs ...)))
    ->setRequired(true);
$this->addElement($email);
```

And when user enter invalid email like `user@email` (without the tld) it show multiple errors like

```
'email' is no valid hostname for email address 'user@email'  
'email' does not match the expected structure for a DNS hostname  
'email' appears to be a local network name but local network names are not allowed
```

I can't use `addErrorMessage('...')` as I need to display different message for invalid email and for email already exists in database. So any idea how to make EmailAddress validation return only 1 error message.

Comment: exact duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239719/in-a-zend-form-how-to-avoid-zend-validate-email-from-generating-multiple-errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me, the problem is not that the messages are overly technical for the average user: that's really a side issue that can be handled by overriding the individual message templates.

For me, the fundamental issue is that this validator inherently returns **multiple** messages and we only want a single message.

I have always had to resort to sub-classing the standard validator:

```
class PapayaSoft_Validate_EmailAddress extends Zend_Validate_EmailAddress
{
    protected $singleErrorMessage = "Email address is invalid";

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $valid = parent::isValid($value);
        if (!$valid) {
            $this->_messages = array($this->getSingleErrorMessage());
        }
        return $valid;
    }

    public function getSingleErrorMessage()
    {
        return $this->singleErrorMessage;
    }

    public function setSingleErrorMessage($singleErrorMessage)
    {
        $this->singleErrorMessage = $singleErrorMessage;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then usage is as follows:

```
$validator = new PapayaSoft_Validate_Email();
$validator->setSingleErrorMessage('Your email is goofy');
$element->addValidator($validator, true);
```

Alternatively, using the short form, you need to add a new namespace prefix for validators so that the short key "EmailAddress" gets picked up from the new non-Zend namespace. Then:

```
$element->addValidator('EmailAddress', true, array(
    'singleErrorMessage' => 'Your email is goofy',
));
```

**Note:** While the [question noted by @emaillenin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239719/in-a-zend-form-how-to-avoid-zend-validate-email-from-generating-multiple-errors) is similar, the accepted answer there does not actually fulfill your requirements. It does set a single error message for the **field**, but it sounds like you need to have **separate** messages coming from the two validators (one for email-format, the other for email-already-exists). For that, it seems to me that you need to change the behavior of the `EmailAddress` validator itself.

Comment: it worked. but I had to manually add the ElementPrefixPath for validator. Is there any way to automatically add the element page

Comment: Internally, the form needs to know how to convert the short name `'EmailAdress'` to the full classname `PapayaSoft_Validate_EmailAdress`. The element prefix paths - pre-configured to include the `Zend_Validate_` namespace - is where this information resides. I usually add my other namespaces - manually, unfortunately - in the form's `init()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can put this one line at end of isValid() funciton but before return false.

```
$this->_messages = array($this->_messageTemplates[self::INVALID]);
```

like this:

```
public function isValid($value)
    {
        if (!is_string($value)) {
            $this->_error(self::INVALID);
            return false;
        }

        $matches = array();
        $length  = true;
        $this->_setValue($value);

        // Split email address up and disallow '..'
        if ((strpos($value, '..') !== false) or
            (!preg_match('/^(.+)@([^@]+)$/', $value, $matches))) {
            $this->_error(self::INVALID_FORMAT);
            return false;
        }

        $this->_localPart = $matches[1];
        $this->_hostname  = $matches[2];

        if ((strlen($this->_localPart) > 64) || (strlen($this->_hostname) > 255)) {
            $length = false;
            $this->_error(self::LENGTH_EXCEEDED);
        }

        // Match hostname part
        if ($this->_options['domain']) {
            $hostname = $this->_validateHostnamePart();
        }

        $local = $this->_validateLocalPart();

        // If both parts valid, return true
        if ($local && $length) {
            if (($this->_options['domain'] && $hostname) || !$this->_options['domain']) {
                return true;
            }
        }

         $this->_messages = array($this->_messageTemplates[self::INVALID]); // ===========By Jagdish Ram JPK --DS-----------

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to write validator like this...

```
$email->addValidator(
    'EmailAddress', 
    true, 
    array( 'messages' => array( 'emailAddressInvalidFormat' => "Email Address is Not Valid... !<br>", "emailAddressInvalidHostname"=>"Email Address is Not Valid... !<br>", "hostnameUnknownTld"=>"Email Address is Not Valid... !<br>","hostnameLocalNameNotAllowed"=>"Email Address is Not Valid... !<br>") )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$po = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$email = $po['email'];
$emval = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
if (!$emval->isValid($email)) {
$this->view->emailerror = "Please enter a valid email ID.";
}
```

And in its view page put the code below where you want to display that error message,

```
       echo $this->emailerror;
```